# aws cli output table as single columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

i'm trying to echo out a table of several values from the aws cli.
the command i'm trying to use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query '{Name:Reservations[*].Instances[].Tags[].Value,Status:Reservations[*].Instances[].State[].Name}' --output table
```

the output i'm getting:

```
-----------------------
|  DescribeInstances  |
+---------------------+
||       Name        ||
|+-------------------+|
||  Agent1           ||
||  Agent2           ||
||  Agent3           ||
||  Agent4           ||
||  Agent5           ||
||  Agent6           ||
||  Agent7           ||
|+-------------------+|
||      Status       ||
|+-------------------+|
||  running          ||
||  running          ||
||  stopped          ||
||  running          ||
||  running          ||
||  stopped          ||
||  running          ||
|+-------------------+|
```

how can i output it as a single table, with 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,Status:State.Name}' --output table
```

The output will be something like this:

```
-----------------------
|  DescribeInstances  |
+---------+-----------+
|  Name   |  Status   |
+---------+-----------+
|  first  |  running  |
|  second |  running  |
+---------+-----------+
```